# Add Component or Directive to HTML template received from the server

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Let's say an endpoint returns this HTML:

```
<div data-type="section">
    <div data-type="section-header">
        Section 1
    </div>
    <div data-type="section-body">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

Above template will be stored in component property `sections`. In an Angular app we will append this HTML to the page via `<div class="sections-container" [innerHtml]="sections"></div>`.

**Before** appending HTML template to `innerHtml`,  is it possible to add *component* or *directive* to the HTML template received from the backend?

For example we have `HighlightDirective`, which will set background to yellow and we want to apply it to `data-type="section-header"` element, so that HTML template will look like this:

```
<div data-type="section">
    <div data-type="section-header" appHighlight>
        Section 1
    </div>
    <div data-type="section-body">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

Will Angular automatically recognize the `appHighlight` directive and add it to the component tree? Or it's necessary to hydrate this HTML template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I have found it is wrapped HTML into anonymous component and handle string from BE. Then compile that and looks like everything is ok.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pw1rlh)