# Click event is not working in dynamically generated HTML from typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, innerhtml, mouseclick-event

Please find my code and help me out if there is any mistake in my code.

Controller.ts

**Generating dynamic HTML code:**

```
    Maintitle = Maintitle + " " + "<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='code-links' (click)='clickLinks();'>" + item.code[0] + "</a>";



      ngAfterViewInit() {
           if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#code-links')) {
                this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#codelinks').addEventListener('click', this.clickLinks.bind(this));
                }
            }
```

**Pipe:**

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    @Pipe({
        name: 'safeHtml'
    })
    export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }
        transform(value) {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
         }

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
     <ul class="list-group list-group-code subTerms">
                <li class="result-success list-group-item strong" *ngFor="let item of xmlTabularContentFinal">
                  <span class="text-muted font-weight-normal"><span> <span [innerHTML]="item.title| safeHtml"></span></span></span>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

While I inspect the elements I could see the event is binding in the html. But the event is not triggered when I click the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since ngAfterViewInit() method executes before the dynamic html could load the event binding was not working. Now I am having an explicit method to bind the event after html content loaded.

Issue is been resolved and working with click event.

Comment: enclosed under a `setTimeout(()=>{..your code..})`

Comment: Exactly the same I did in my code. Thanks for the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a solution for your case: [render dynamic code from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456687/add-component-or-directive-to-html-template-received-from-the-server/69502605#69502605)

Main idea that you need to create an anonymous component and module and then render it in component.

Comment: But in my case I am generating a list of elements and these would be dynamically added in the same component. Based on the click event I have to do few other logics. Is there any possibility of doing it in the same component?